# mysqldumpを使用せず、MySQLのデータをリカバリーする方法

Tags: mysql

MySQLのtableデータを保存するにあたり、一番簡単な方法はmysqldumpだと思います。
しかし、今回自分に起こった問題は、serverをrebootしたときに、MySQLの一部のファイルで問題が起こり、mysql自体が起動しなくなってしまいました。（それに伴ってmysqldumpも使用できませんでした。）

最終的には自己解決しましたが、かなりはまってしまった困っておりました。
この状況で、データを保存して、新しくMySQLを入れなおし、その保存したデータを新規のMySQLに入れなおした過程を残しておきます。この方法がすべてとは思いませんが、自分の場合ではデータがリカバリーできました。

以下に移動させました。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 役立つ内容かもしれませんが、回答は質問文に含めるべきではないと思います。

Comment: StackOverflowはQ&Aのサイトです。せっかく役に立つ内容ですので、上記の内容からAの部分を消し、Aの部分は回答として投稿して頂けませんか。自分の質問に自分で回答をつけることは問題ありません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今回使用した環境は、
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
MySQL version: 5.7.20 (現時点でubuntuのapt-getで得られる最新のversionです。)

１・　データの保存！
これは一番重要です。mysqlのデータをすべて保存します。自分のサーバーでは、/var/lib/mysqlがそれにあたります。まずはこれのback-upを作成します。

```
sudo cp -r /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.bak
```

(mysql directoryはmysqlが管理者になっていると思いますので、"sudo"をコマンドの頭に付けます。)

２．壊れた（古い）versionのMySQLをすべて取り除く
これは以下のコマンドでできます。

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

また、古いデータが残っていると邪魔しますので、データが保存されているdirectoryを消去します。

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

3．MySQLの再インストール
これは以下のcommandで大丈夫です。

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

なぜかわかりませんが、今回行った時には、同じcommandでも2パターンの結果が出てきました。
パターン１（正解）：上記のcommandを動かすと、自動的に、root passwordが訊かれます。このroot passwordを設定すれば、以後問題は起こりませんでした。ですので、こちら方を今回の問題に関して「正解」と記させていただきます。
パターン２（問題が残る）：上記で記したroot passwordが訊かれませんが、なぜかinstallが完了します。これは後々データを移動させるときに問題になってきます。もし訊かれなかった場合、２からやり直してください。（再度mysqlを消して、再インストールです。）

インストールが終了すると、さっき消した/var/lib/mysqlが復活しているはずです。

```
sudo ls /var/lib/mysql
```

で確かめれます。
念のため、この時点でmysqlにlog-inできるかを確かめておいてください。

```
mysql -u root -p
```

4. データの移動
   back-upを取ったdirectoryからデータを移動させます。
   この時に重要になるファイル・directoryが３種類あります。

   - ib* (ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1)
   - performance_schema(これも標準でついているdirectoryです。)
   - リカバリーさせたいデータ(databaseの名前ごとに、directoryで整理されていると思います。)

以下のcommandをタイプすると大丈夫です。

```
sudo cp /var/lib/mysql.bak/ib* /var/lib/mysql/ib*
sudo cp -r /var/lib/mysql.bak/performance_schema /var/lib/mysql/performance_schema
sudo cp -r /var/lib/mysql.bak/<リカバリーさせたいdatabase名> /var/lib/mysql/<リカバリーさせたいdatabase名>
```

(もし[リカバリーさせたいdatabase]が複数ある場合は、最後の行を繰り返してください。)
directoryの管理が違っているかもしれませんので、以下のもので管理をしてください。

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/ib*
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/performance_schema
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/<リカバリーさせたいdatabase名>
```

5. (オプション) 一度MySQLにログインする
   先にもやりました、

   mysql -u root -p

でログインした後、

```
show database
```

でリカバリーさせたいdatabase名が表示されることを確認してください。
さらに

```
use <リカバリーさせたいdatabase名>
show table
```

で、テーブル名が見えることもお忘れずに。
しかし、この時点では、

```
select * from table_name;
```

を行ったとしても、エラーが出ると思います。（例えば、ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'v3_zone_date_cpm7k' doesn't exist）
この状態では、テーブル名が表示されれば十分ですので、気にせず、ログアウトしてください。

6. mysqlを再起動する
   以下のcommandでmysqlが再起動できます。

   sudo service mysql restart

もしくは

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

確認のために、上記の後に、

```
sudo service mysql status
```

もしくは

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status
```

で「Active: active (running) 」が見えるか確認してください。

7. MySQLに再度ログインする
   再度mysqlにログインすると、すべてのデータはリカバリーされていると思います。
   これで終了です。:)

最後に、少し注意点は、
例えば、保存されているdirectory(/var/lib/mysql.bak)のなかに以前に作成したdatabaseが３つあると仮定してください。(PROJECT_ONE, PROJECT_TWO, PROJECT_THREE)
たとえ、この中のPROJECT_ONEだけをリカバリーしたい場合でも、３つともすべてデータを移動させてください。もしこれを行わないと、#6のmysqlの再起動の時に問題が発生します。（基本再起動できませんでした。）

ただ、上記のように行ったところ、うまくいきましたので、もしお困りの方がおられましたら、参考程度に試していただけると幸いです。

Comment: もしよければ、ご自身で この質問に 「解決マーク」をつけてください。そうすればこの質問は 解決済みのQAであることが 分かるようになります。

Comment: すみませんでした。当時やり方が分からず、そのままになっておりました。ご指摘の通り、解決マークをつけておきました。ご指摘、ありがとうございました。